# PhoneGap local notifications not working

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm checking PhoneGap project via PhoneGap Desktop (Win 10) on a devices with Adobe PhoneGap mobile apps on the systems: Android: 5.1.1, iOS: 10.2.1.

I have this line in config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notifications" source="npm" />
```

I can see that files are downloaded in the project's 'plugins' folder.

JavaScript code is:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () 
{
    var now = new Date().getTime(),
    _10_seconds_from_now = new Date(now + 10*1000);

    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
       id:      1,
       title:   'Some Timer',
       message: 'Some Message',
       at:      _10_seconds_from_now
    });

}, false);
```

Nothing happens at all.

I checked like this:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () 
{
    alert(cordova.plugins.notification);
}, false);
```

and the result is:

```
Undefined
```

Hence I couldn't found the plugin in the list:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(cordova.plugins));
```

Strange, but I got only barcodeScanner there, which I'm not using at all.
So, as I guess I have more plugins installation problem then coding one.

I tried to use several repositories like

```
<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" source="npm" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-local-notifications-mm" source="npm" />
```

Got the same results.

I also built APK on https://build.phonegap.com, just to check if something is wrong with Adobe's PhoneGap mobile apps, APK was made successfully but got the same results - nothing happens at all.

What you might suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I learned it's PhoneGap Desktop's problem, need to work manually with PhoneGap CLI.

While testing on https://build.phonegap.com need to remember to delete 'plugins' and 'platforms' directories' content and only after it make zip file for an upload.